# Proof of the Vivanti-Pringsheim Theorem.

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification

Here's the result which I'm trying to prove.

Let the power series $z \mapsto f(z) = \sum a_n z^n$ have positive finite radius of convergence $R$ and suppose that all but finitely many of its coefficients $a_n$ are real and non-negative. Then, $z = R$ is a singular point of $f$.

---

**Proof Attempt:**

WLOG, we can assume that $R = 1$. Suppose that the given power series converges at $z = 1$. Then, the series $\sum a_n$ converges. Now, consider all $z \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $|z| = 1$. So, now, consider the series:

$$\sum |a_n z^n| = \sum |a_n| = \sum a_n$$

where the last equality is justified by omitting as many terms in the series as necessary so that we only have non-negative terms left. This also justifies the removal of the absolute value. So, it follows that the power series converges on the entire boundary and this contradicts a result which guarantees the existence of a singular point on the boundary. $\Box$

Does this proof work? If it doesn't, then why? How can I fix it?

Comment: unfortunately knowing just that $1$ is not a singular point does not imply _in general_ that the power series converges at $1$. (In fact $1/(z-1)=1+z+z^2+\dots$ has only one singular point on the unit circle but diverges at every point of the unit circle...))

Comment: Oof yea let me try this again and see if I can come up with an argument that works

Comment: If by contradiction, $1$ is not singular let all Taylor coefficients at zero be non negative by subtracting a polynomial;consider the power series centered at $1$ with radius $r>0$ and show its coefficients  are non negative by showing that they are left radial limits of the appropriate formula in the original coefficients  at zero where non negativity is crucial (this is a form of the monotone convergence  theorem for integrals); then one easily switches the double series that appears to show that one extends the original  series to a higher $1+r$ radius getting the contradiction  required